# HTML page is nesting sibling divs

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML page ([see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/u7sxqu2e/5/)) that contains a parent div with three children divs. I'm expecting to see the three divs one next to the other. Instead, I see that each child div is contained inside its sibling.

My web page HTML contains this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div11" />
    <div id="div12" />
    <div id="div13"/>
</div>
```

however when I do "Inspect element" (in both IE and Chrome) I get this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div11">
        <div id="div12">
            <div id="div13"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

What's wrong with this markup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div>` elements are not self-closing in HTML4 or HTML5; you need to add an end tag for each one. Thus this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div11" />
    <div id="div12" />
    <div id="div13"/>
</div>
```

should be this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div11"></div>
    <div id="div12"></div>
    <div id="div13"></div>
</div>
```

The browser will fill in the missing closing tags, which is why you've got the nested structure--the browser assumes that the tree was supposed to be nested and closes the tags appropriately.

You can always run your code through an HTML validator (e.g. http://validator.w3.org) to check for simple errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

*Div* is an open-close tag. 
you should specify the open tag `<div>` with the siblings as you did in the parent *div* .
here's the right markup

```
<div id="div1">

  <div id="div11">
  </div><!--end div11-->

  <div id="div12">
  </div><!--end div12-->

  <div id="div13">
  </div><!--end div13-->

</div><!--end parent div-->
```

Comment: your answer is correct, however "I alarmed alien" answered before you did